# Select a variable inside .click() event in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I can select a variable inside .click() in jquery this is the code:

```
    $('#text-box').click(function(){
       var type = $(this).val();
    }); 
     alert(type);// this will not get alerted
```

How I can alert `type`? I dont want it to get alerted when it got clicked

```
<input type='text' id='text-box'>
```

Comment: give the html to see what is going on

Comment: In that case `type` cannot be local to your click event handler. It must be an outer scope accessible to both the click handler and where you want to alert it.

Comment: @SudhanshuSaxena - HTML won't be of much help for this particular question.

Comment: @techfoobar i just thought if the `ID` or `Value` is missing or garbaged,,,there it is-- no value in the text box also.

Answer (score 4):

Define it outside of handler to get it out side of handler in some other function. The way you have alerted it outside handler will alert the initially assigned value but not when was in assigned in `click` handler.

```
var type = "0";
$('#text-box').click(function(){
   type = $(this).val();
}); 
alert(type);// Now this will get alerted but before click with initial value i.e. 0
```

If `#text-box` is a `textbox` then you probably want `change / keyup` event instead of click.

To see the stored value after click in type variable you can add a button and bind click event to it to see what is in type variable. Make sure you trigger the `#text-box` event before you click the button

```
$('#someButtonId').click(function(){
    alert(type);
});
```

Comment: It should alert 0 as the alert statement is executed well before the click event is triggered.

Comment: Why not the value of the textbox?

Comment: because it is not yet assigned. The alert is executed before that probably when document got ready / page load. See my answer for more understanding

Answer (score 0):

Should be done like this- first define the type variable to give the variable scope out of the function so that you can access it outside the `click()` function

```
var type =0;
$('#text-box').click(function(){
 type = $(this).val();
}); 
 alert(type);
```

Answer (score 0):

See you have to put all your code in `doc ready` handler:

```
$(function(){
   var type = ''; // declare outside of event here
   $('#text-box').click(function(){
      type = $(this).val(); // update the value in the var type here
   }).trigger('click'); // <----this triggers the click on load to update the val
   alert(type);// now this will get alerted 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Watch.JS](https://github.com/melanke/Watch.JS) you can manage the watch on variable change..

This is a simple example:

http://jsfiddle.net/4QLUu/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var watched = {value:0};
  watch(watched,"value", function(){
    console.log(watched.value);
 });

 $('#text-box').on("change",function(){
     console.log($(this).val());
   watched.value = $(this).val();
 }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two way to do this first way you check in above code if if there is a requirement that you can not define this variable outside this function then you should use session object(Web Storage).

```
  $('#text-box').click(function(){
        sessionStorage.setItem(key,$(this).val());
    });
        var item = sessionStorage.getItem(key);
        alert(key);
```